# Identify the ugcPost owner without the closed permission r_member_social

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm struggling to identify the user (ugcPost owner) who shared a company post using the Social Action Notifications API without the r_member_social permission.

I'm using the Social Action Notifications API to monitor linkedin company pages and track employee/users engagement.

When an employee/users shares a company post, an event with action "SHARE" is raised with containing the corresponding ugcPost urn but without information regarding who was the employee/users that created the share. Like the example below.

```
{
    "type": "ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS",
    "notifications": [
        {
            "subscriber": "urn:li:person:AAAAAAAA",
            "lastModifiedAt": 1692624354009,
            "sourcePost": "urn:li:activity:000000000000000000",
            "action": "SHARE",
            "notificationId": 5641847425,
            "organizationalEntity": "urn:li:organization:000000",
            "generatedActivity": "urn:li:ugcPost:1111111111111111"
        }
    ]
}
```

The [Social Actions API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions?view=li-lms-unversioned&tabs=http#retrieve-social-actions) could be used to retrieve the ugcPost but it requires the closed permission `r_member_social` for which linkedin is not accepting access requests like explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/lms-faq?view=li-lms-2023-07#how-do-i-get-access-to-r_member_social).

How could we identify the ugcPost owner without the closed permission `r_member_social`?